# Is there a better way to deal with DoesNotExist query sets

Tags: python, django

There is probably a better way of dealing with non existant query sets...!
The problem i have with this code is that it raises an exception if the normal case will be true! That is: if a workspace name with the same name in the db is not existent.

But instead of having an exception i would like to go for a query that does not return DoesNotExist but true or false

My unelegant code:

```
 try:
            is_workspace_name = Workspace.objects.get(workspace_name=workspace_name,user=self.user.id )
 except:
        return workspace_name
 if is_workspace_name:
            raise forms.ValidationError(u'%s already exists as a workspace name! Please choose a different one!' %workspace_name  )
```

Thanks a lot!

Comment: this is EAFP style the alternative is LBYL ... EAFP is widely accepted in python... but it should probably not be a naked exception but rather `except DoesNotExist:`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [exists()](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#exists) method. Quoting docs:

> Returns True if the QuerySet contains any results, and False if not.
>   This tries to perform the query in the simplest and fastest way
>   possible, but it does execute nearly the same query as a normal
>   QuerySet query.

Remarks:  ***the simplest and fastest way.*** It is cheaper to use `exists` (than `count`) because with `exists` the database stops counting at first occurrence.

```
if Workspace.objects.filter(workspace_name=workspace_name, 
                            user=self.user.id).exists()
    raise forms.ValidationError(u'%s already exists ...!' % workspace_name)
else:
    return workspace_name
```

Comment: I believe that `Queryset.get` will actually do the query. If the record doesn't exist, you code won't even reach the point of running `Workspace.exists` (which happens to not be defined as it's a `Queryset` method). You probably want to be using `filter` and not `get`.

Comment: @ThomasOrozco. Ups! Thanks a lot about your comment! Fixed now for you?

Comment: Yes, I didn't know about `Queryset.exists`, that's interesting!

Answer (score 1):

### Checking for the existence of a record.

If you want to test for the existence of a record in your database, you could be using `Workspace.objects.filter(workspace_name = workspace_name,user = self.user.id).count()`.

This will return the number of records matching your conditions. This number will be 0 in case there is none, which will be readily usable with an `if` clause. I believe this to me the most standard and easy way to do what you need here.

**## EDIT ## Actually that's false, you might want to check danihp's answer for a better solution using `Queryset.exists`!**

### A word of warning: the case of checking for existence before insertion

Be cautious when using such a construct however, especially if you plan on checking whether you have a duplicate before trying to insert a record. In such a case, the best solution is to try to create the record and see if it raises an exception.

Indeed, you could be in the following situation:

1. Request 1 reaches the server
2. Request 2 reaches the server
3. Check is done for request 1, no object exist.
4. Check is done for request 2, no object exist.
5. Proceed with creation in request 1.
6. Proceed with creation in request 2.

And... you have a duplicate - this is called a [race condition](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Race_condition#Example), and is a common issue when dealing with parallel code.

**Long story short**, you should use `try`, `expect` and `unique` constraints when  dealing with insertion.

Using `get_or_create`, as suggested by init3, also helps. Indeed, [`get_or_create` is aware of this](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/db/models/query.py#L469), and you'll be safe so long as unwanted duplicated would raise an `IntegrityError`

Answer (score 0):

```
obj, created = Workspace.objects.get_or_create(workspace_name=workspace_name, user=self.user.id)

if created:
    # everything ok
    # do something
    pass
else:
    # not ok
    # respond he should choose anything else
    pass
```

[read more at the docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#get-or-create)

Comment: @ini3 for me that does not work because this code lives in the forms.py but in views i would take your solution...

Comment: in forms? oh, ok. could I see an example? *edit* my fault - fingers faster than brain and eyes. got it now :)